# How to load resources using IntentService, so they can be used later for some Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, intentservice

first time posting question here :)

I am developing an **Android** app that needs a resource from an URL, and uses an **IntentService** to load it.

This app has 3 activities:

- Activity **W**: welcome activity, has some settings, can open A or B.
- Activity **A**: does some work with the resource from the URL.
- Activity **B**: does some work with the resource from the URL.

Activity **W** starts the **IntentService** automatically so it can begin loading the resource in the background in order to save time. This way when the user reaches activities **A** or **B**, wich need the resource, the work is done or almost done.

**PROBLEM**: when the **IntentService** successfully loads the resource, it doesn't know wich **Activity** is on display. Maybe the user is still on Activity **W**, or maybe it's on **A** or **B**.

**QUESTION**: how can I *easily* deliver the resource (it's an ArrayList) from the **IntentService** to Activities **A** or **B**, whichever is on display? In case the user is still on **W**, where to put the resource so it can be retrieved later by **A** or **B**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for this is to use a BroadcastReceiver. If your IntentService is done with the work it broadcasts the results. Your Activities have to implement the receiver, to be able to get the broadcast. Keep in mind to register and unregister the receiver accordingly in your Activities.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) how to use it.

Comment: Note that in order to get the loaded resources in your activity, you need to pass them with an intent, that is, they must be Parcelable. Alternatively you can store and later retrieve them in your activity through an Uri.

Comment: @Steve thank you for your answer, but I was thinking, what if the IntentService performs the broadcast when the user changes between Activities? There might be some range of time where no receiver is listening to the broadcast. What would happen then? is there a better solution to do this?

Comment: @type-a1pha thank you for your comment, but I don't understand what you mean by storing the resource (ArrayList) and retrieving it through an URI. Where/how would you store it so it can be used by another Activity? Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: IntentServices (and more in general Services) and BroadcastReceivers implements a form of IPC that uses messages to communicate. You can't store a reference in a message, since references can't jump across different processes. So if you want to pass an object you need either to turn it into a form that a message can deliver (i.e. Parcelable) or, if for example you need to pass data downloaded from the web, you can first store this data in a file on the disk and then retrieve this data throught the file path in the file system, i.e. the uri.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use to [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).